# Azure SQL Database Mapping Entities Options

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database where I host external vendor information and I also have a SQL Server running for my web application.

I need to retrieve and update data to the SQL Azure database with some of my data that I extract and modify from my local SQL database.

Now for the question....

Do I use Entity Framework for the SQL Azure Database and create an entity model? Or is there a better method for CRUD operations for SQL Azure database?

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its fine to do CRUD operations via EF on SQL Azure Database.
But do the operations on Worker Role. Worker Role will be running all the time and you can have better control of your models.